# Laravel Pagination Item Numbering API

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, pagination, numbers

How can I return the item number of the resource in API with pagination?

the number used for the table of items, so if the page 1 have 5 item, the number on page 2 will continue begin from 6 to 10.

i use the `paginate()` function as usual

my JSON now is like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "foto": null,
                "nik": "292680381382302",
                "nama": "Admin",
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://pmo-9.test/api/karyawan?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://pmo-9.test/api/karyawan?page=1",
        "links": [
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "&laquo; Previous",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "url": "http://pmo-9.test/api/karyawan?page=1",
                "label": "1",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "Next &raquo;",
                "active": false
            }
        ],
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://pmo-9.test/api/karyawan",
        "per_page": "5",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

how can I add the `number: 1` column to the response?

Comment: why do you want to add the ``number`` property? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: it used for the numbering on the table (UI), so if the page is 2, the number will continue after page one

Comment: It's not clear what your asking/explaining‼️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution for my question

```
$collection->each(function ($collect, $index) use ($collection) {
   $collect->nomor = $collection->perPage() * ($collection->currentPage() - 1) + $index + 1;
});
```

as the `$collection` is `Model::paginate();`.

that's it

Answer (score 0):

You data length will give you this number. If you are using JS then just use data.length to achieve it.